# Proof for number of completely odd and even subsets.

Tags: combinatorics

While studying, I read this: "A subset of integers $1,2,...,n$ has the property that the sum of its members is odd. The number of such subsets is $2^{n-1}$."

I also read this: "A subset of integers $1,2,...,n$ has the property that the sum of its members is even. The number of such subsets is $2^{n-1}-1$."

The book doesn't go into detail when explaining the proofs for these formulas. I would be glad of any assistance if anyone could explain the proofs to these two formulas.

Comment: Inducting on $n$ will work

Comment: You seem to tacitly be assuming that all sets are nonempty somewhere here. And that $n$ is positive.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

induction for $n=1$ we have $2^{1-1}=1$ odd subsets and $2^{1-1}-1=0$ even subsets.

now assume that for $n=k$ we have $2^{k-1}$ odd subsets and $2^{k-1}-1$ even subsets.

what happens when we add the number $k+1$ - two cases

if $k+1$ is even then including it in a subset will not change its parity ( whether it is odd or even ) so you can get an even subset by

1. not including $k+1$ and counting the number of even subsets with
   maximum element $k$ , which gives $2^{k-1}-1 $ subsets
2. Add the number $k+1$ to each of the even subsets with maximum
   element $k$  - since this won't change parity this will make an
   additional $2^{k-1}-1 $ subsets
3. The one subset containing just the number $k+1$ will be even

so the total number of even subsets will be

$$ (2^{k-1}-1) + (2^{k-1}-1) + 1 = 2^k - 1 $$

as required. You should now be able to count the odd subsets and get $2^k$ and also show that the same results hold if $k+1$ is odd

Answer (score 1):

First note that there are actually $2^n$ many subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, but if we do not consider the empty set, then there are $2^n-1=2^{n-1}+(2^{n-1}-1)$ many subsets.

Now, I also consider empty subset as a subset whose sum is even, i.e. $0$. Given a subset $S$ whose sum is odd, we can one-to-one correspond it to the symmetric difference of $S$ and $\{1\}$, call it $T$. Note that the sum of $T$ is even, therefore there are as many (that is $2^n/2=2^{n-1}$) odd subsets as even subsets. Hence, the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

The number of subsets of $I_n = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ is $2^{n}$ you can use the multiplication principle. each time you decide if the element enters or not your subset. This gives you a $n$ bifurcations, yes or no.

Consider any subset without $1$. you have that the sum is either odd, or even. There are $2^{n-1}$ subsets without the $1$. Since you can decide whether to include or not the number $1$ (if it is odd then you don't include the $1$, if it is even you include). you obtain $2^{n-1}$ subsets whose sum is odd, and in the same manner $2^{n-1}$ whose sum is even

Comment: There are only $2^{n-1}-1$ whose sum are even unless you say the emptyset gets a zero sum or something like that

Comment: @bburGsamohT: Yes simply by definition of the sum of a finite set of numbers, the empty set has sum $0$.

Comment: @bburGsamohT You are kindly referred to my solution, actually I post my solution before Conrado, and his solution is just the same as mine :)

Comment: @Salomo the difference being you explicitly stated your assumption about the empty set. In the statement of the question, the OP said the number of even sums should be $2^{n-1}-1$. I am simply saying it would be nice to make this clear to the OP.

Comment: @bburGsamohT wow, such a great job!